# drupal comment post api not using form api

Tags: drupal, comments, form-api

I want to create an api for commenting in Drupal. Question is Is there something out there already for me to reuse so that I don't have to create the complete comment object structure through my code.

My Drupal 7 comment post api will be backend to a mobile so it will be exposed as a restful service. I debugged the Form API on how the comment object is created and want to stay away from the hassle of development and testing

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the [Services module](http://drupal.org/project/services). It gives you the possibility to expose the Drupal comment object as a RESTful service. You can then just send comments as JSON (or XML, SOAP, etc) to the REST endpoint, which will take care of storing it in Drupal.